# Alahuma Salee w salem ala sydna muhammad?

Tags: salat, dua, salawat

What is the meaning of the following (Alahuma Salee w salem ala sydna muhammad), is the salaa mentioned here is the same sala that we perform, asking this to understand how can we say Allah prays(Salee) muhammed, what is the definition of the word prays in this context?

brothers and sisters please explain and clarify, jazakum allah kher all of you!

Answer (score 1):

No its not the same saleh that we preform. This one means *honor* so we are asking allah to honor our prophet **not** to *pray* to him but to honor him

Answer (score 0):

The definition of prays means "blessings" or "peace" in the following context.

> Indeed, Allah confers blessing upon the Prophet, and His angels [ask Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [ Allah to confer] blessing upon him and ask [ Allah to grant him] peace. (Qur'an 33:56).

The question you asked in it's correct form means,

> O Allah, let Your Peace come upon Muhammad

May the creator guide us all.